# Need to access the ID of autocomplete comboBox in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

**i want to retrive id of Combobox on key event(or on Change:) written below 
try to see the CHANGE:function in below code and suggest some tips**
i want to retrive id of Combobox on key event(or on Change:) written below 
try to see the CHANGE:function in below code and suggest some tips

```
(function($) {
 $.widget("ui.combobox", {
     _create: function() {
         var input, self = this, select = this.element.hide(), selected = select.children(":selected"), value = selected.val() ?
 selected.text() : "", wrapper = this.wrapper =
 $("<span>").addClass("ui-combobox").insertAfter(select);

         input = $("<input>")
                .appendTo(wrapper)
                .val(value)
                .addClass("ui-state-default ui-combobox-input")
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function(request, response) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                        response(select.children("option").map(function() {
                            var text = $(this).text();
                            if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
                            // alert(text);
                                return {
                                    label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                                            "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                            ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                        ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }));
                    },

                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        self._trigger("selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
                    },
                    change: function(event, ui) {
                        // alert($(event.target)[0].id);
                        //alert($(this).attr('id'));
                        alert(event.target.id);
                        if (!ui.item) {
                            xT = $(this).val();
                            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                                valid = false;
                            select.children("option").each(function() {
                                if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                                    this.selected = valid = true;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            if (!valid) {
                                xT = $(this).val();
                                $(".selPnext").show();
                                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                // $(this).val("");
                                // select.val("");
                                // input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
         //.addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

         input.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
             return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
         };

         $("<a>")
                .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                .appendTo(wrapper)
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
                .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-combobox-toggle")
                .click(function() {
                    // close if already visible
                    if (input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
                        input.autocomplete("close");
                        return;
                    }

                    // work around a bug (likely same cause as #5265)
                    $(this).blur();

                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete("search", "");
                    input.focus();
                });
     },

     destroy: function() {
         this.wrapper.remove();
         this.element.show();
         $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
     }
 }); })(jQuery); var xT; function myVal() {
 return xT; } $(function() {
 //$("#tryy").combobox();
 //$("#country").combobox(); });
```

Comment: jquery autoComplete ComboBox

Comment: I see a whole lot of code but what is your issue?

Comment: on change:  i need to retrive id of Combox 
i used sme techniques bt nthing hapned

Comment: Err, you already have the input element as `input` when you're creating the jQuery input element, so why don't you just do `input.attr('id')` or `input[0].id`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign an id to the combobox:

```
$("<input>").attr('id', 'something')
```

Then onChange:

```
$('#something').live('change', function(){
  var id = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: seems like you wrapped your code in a closure. Just place it anywhere inside the closure: (function(){ //somewhere here })(jQuery); for the adding of id all you have to do is to edit this existing code:  input = $("<input>").appendTo(wrapper).val(value)